# How to select a button by default on activity run?

Tags: java, button, uibutton, radio-button

I want to include two simple buttons in my activity, for example, "Start" and "End".
Now i want "Start" button to be selected by default (with any background color) when i run my activity. How to do that through java in Android studio?
Note:- i am not talking about radio button's small circle. I am talking about simple button.

Answer (score 0):

use setBackgroundColor method.

```
  btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
         // your code here
        }
    });
```

Comment: i wrote that code inside onCreate method but it didn't work. The app crashed on run.

Comment: see your logcat you get why the app is crashing